# Getting the values from hash

Tags: r, hashmap

I have a dataframe whose contents looks like this,

```
   V1 V2
00:00  3
00:01  5
00:02  3
00:03  3
00:04  1
00:05  3
```

To make it into key vales for hash I do some modifications.

```
mins <- ndata[,1]
vols <- ndata[,2]
mins <- as.character(mins)
vols <- as.character(vols)
head(mins) # "00:00" "00:01" "00:02" "00:03" "00:04" "00:05"
head(vols) # "3" "5" "3" "3" "1" "3"
hh <- hash(keys= mins, values=vols)
.set(hh,keys= mins, values=vols)
hh["23:59" ]
hh$"23:59"

for(t in ls(hh))
{
  print(hh$t) # NULL
  print(hh[ t ]) ## <hash> containing 1 key-value pair(s).  23:57 : 3
  val <- c(val,hh$t)
}
```

I cannot access them using hh$t where t is my iterator variable(It returns `NULL`) while the other methods emits a like `<hash> containing 1 key-value pair(s).  23:57 : 3`.

But, outside of the loop with specific value I can access them easily.

`hh$"23:59"` gives me the expected value `[1] "4"`. What is the right method to get the values from a hash object inside a loop formed out of its keys ?

Answer (score 2):

This is a rather fundamental difference between `$` and `[`. Basically, you should only use the former interactively at the command line, and only use the latter when programming.

`hh$t` will always be interpreted by R as looking for something *called* `t`, not called "the value stored in `t`". That's why it works when you use `$` with the (quoted) name directly.

In particular, see the section called "Recursive (list-like) objects" in the documentation under `?Extract`.